# Switching TV to DVI input via HDMI / CEC

Tags: hdmi

I have a Samsung TV / monitor with HDMI, DVI, VGA inputs and more. My Raspberry Pi is connected to the HDMI input, my computer to the DVI input. With

```
echo as | cec-client -s -d 1
```

executed on the Pi, I can change the input of the TV to HDMI. As far as I know, DVI does not support CEC. This means I can't execute above command on my computer to make the TV switch to the DVI input.

Is it possible to send a CEC command from the Pi via HDMI to the TV to make it switch to DVI?

Comment: Note sure if that is possible. But you could try adding a IR-led to one of the GPIO's and make the Pi send the correct IR command to switch inputs. Look into `lirc` for this.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to edit the keymap to cause a certain action to trigger the switch the DVI.
You haven't specified which OS you are using, but there's some (limited) guidance on modifying the keymap file for it [here](http://kodi.wiki/view/Keymap#Remotes). There should be a similar configuration file for other OS's

What I suspect you'll need to do is:

1. Determine the CEC command for your particular model monitor - to change to DVI;
2. Then map this to whatever key/button you want.*

**Note**: My Samsung TV remote doesn't have a single button to switch across. I need to choose source, navigate to the DVI source, then press enter. This might require some script so that a single key press executes several commands in sequence. Though I've never done this, so can't confirm it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

The two ways that may work are:

1. Determine the command or code to use with User Control Pressed or Vendor Remote Button Down (I'd use [CEC-O-MATIC](http://www.cec-o-matic.com/) to build the message. You'd need to use the cec-client `tx` command with what you generate on the site.)
2. Send the Inactive Source command (`is`). It is up to the TV manufacturer to decide how the TV reacts to this, but some TVs go back to the previously selected source.